# VueJS Not emit message to parent

Tags: vue.js

I don't have much knowledge about child and parent component and i am just simply trying to change value in child then emit then value to parent so i can show somewhere, But it looks like not working, Not emiting the value.

This should change to : Hello from child

`{{ message }}` From Parent

Can anyone look this code and tell me what is mistake ?

```js
Vue.component('child1', {
 template: '<p @click="runMe">{{ display }}</p>',
  props: ['display'],  
  data: {
   display: ''
  },
  methods: {
   runMe() {
     this.display = "Hello from child"
   this.$emit("changeMessage", this.display)
    }    
  }
})

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   message: "Hello 2"
  },    
  methods: {
   messageRun() {
   this.message = "Change By"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.btnMain {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <button @click="messageRun" class="btnMain">Click Here</button>
    <child1 :display="message" @changeMessage="message = $event"></child1>
    <hr>
    {{ message }} From Parent
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have this where you emit:

```
this.$emit("changeMessage", this.display)
```

Change to :

```
this.$emit("newmessage", this.display)
```

I mean use lower case single word, if you use camelCase vue convert it to change-message but this is not acceptable by attribute, I tried this on your code.

After change this do this :

```
<child1 :display="message" @newmessage="message = $event"></child1>
```

Comment: Vuejs currently doesn't support [camelCase](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2669) on `v-on`.